# JQuery - need to identify some events related to input textbox

Tags: jquery, events

I am looking to figure out some new JQuery events. Something to like Twitter has on their signup page (and plenty of other signup pages throughout the web), https://twitter.com/signup, that would be great. It seems like they have the following events (I have added some extra that I would like):

1. Press enter in textbox - after text has been entered
2. Press enter in textbox - no text present
3. Click another textbox - same two events as above
4. Identify characters typed in textbox - i.e. # of characters, numbers, special characters, etc.
5. Characters typed in one textbox match another textbox
6. Verify username - I assume this is linked to the backend databases in some form...
7. Only let you hit submit if textboxes have the accurate information.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have enough time to do all of them, but look here http://jsfiddle.net/Q3uJM/ for examples of 1, 2, 3, 5

I'm sure you can figure out 4 and 7 now I have provided that foundation. 6 would require an ajax call and some server side code. jQuery had very nice ajax functions, but I can't help on the server side stuff

Answer (score 0):

Google jquery .val(). 
And just run the tests you need on the inputs you want to check.

Basically just google every question you wrote.